# Dart: Obtaining a list from map's key-value

Tags: dart, functional-programming

The following code works (`blend1` is equal to `blend2`) , but it's quite ugly:

1. The iteration should be over map entries, not over keys.
2. It's pointless to catch a non-existing value when iterating over the keys.
3. The expression `colors[key]` makes it slower than necessary.

```
void main() {
  final colors = {
    '1': 'red',
    '2': 'green',
    '3': 'blue'
  };

  final blend1 = colors.keys.map((key) => key + '-' + (colors[key] ?? ''));

  print(blend1);

  final blend2 = [
    '1-red',
    '2-green',
    '3-blue'
  ];

  print(blend2);
}
```

Can you suggest something nicer? I gather that I need to use `colors.entries`, but the result of `colors.entries.map` is a `map`, not a `list`.

Comment: Weird.. the usual indent-by-four-spaces to format code no longer works. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess it's now obsolete, and the triple ticks is the new method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colors.entries.map`.

> the result of `colors.entries.map` is a `map`, not a `list`.

The result of that is neither a `Map` nor a `List`, [`.entries`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Map/entries.html) returns an `Iterable<MapEntry<K, V>>`. A [`MapEntry`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/MapEntry-class.html) is just a class containing the `key` and `value` as properties.

Then calling [`.map`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) on an `Iterable<MapEntry<K, V>>` will give you an `Iterable<T>`, where `T` is whatever type you return in the callback function, in this case a `String`.

```dart
void main() {
  final colors = {'1': 'red', '2': 'green', '3': 'blue'};

  final blend1 = colors.entries.map((entry) => '${entry.key}-${entry.value}');

  print(blend1);

  final blend2 = ['1-red', '2-green', '3-blue'];

  print(blend2);
}
```

If you want the result to be a `List<String>` instead of an `Iterable<String>` you can simply add a call to `.toList()`.

```dart
final blend1 = colors.entries.map((entry) => '${entry.key}-${entry.value}').toList();
```

Or you can use a [`collection-for`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) on a `List` literal.

```dart
final blend1 = [for (final entry in colors.entries) '${entry.key}-${entry.value}'];
```